# apa6e referencing required for elsevier article

Tags: cross-referencing

I need apa6e referencing style for an Elsevier article. I don't know why I encounter errors. Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\journal{Expert Systems with Applications}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{Hybrid}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: @Harish I edited the post

Comment: Are you using `\cite` some where in the document?

Comment: Yes I do use \cite as well as \citep

Comment: It works well if I use apalike referencing but error comes when i use apacite

Comment: This is the same question as #212557. See the answer provided there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212557/