# Elsevier article with APA references

Tags: apa-style, elsarticle

I'm writing an article for Elsevier Journal which follows APA6e references; everything is fine except that the article starts from page 2 leaving page 1 blank with just `double hyphen (==)` in the middle. Here is how I write.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\journal{Expert Systems with Applications}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{myrefers}

\end{document}
```

How Can I rectify the problem?

Comment: Your first step should be by providing the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) (please click and read this link) that replicates your problem. I notice that you open a `frontmatter` environment, but never close it. Then you also use a bibliography `myrefers` that we never see. Are all the packages you load really necessary?

Comment: Looks like some problem with `apacite`.

Comment: @Werner: Even if I put frontmatter in comments, I still get first page blank. My bib file is as: 
@article{Freitas,
 author = { F.D. Freitas and A.F. de Souza and A.R. de Almeida},
 title = {Prediction-based portfolio optimization using neural networks},
 journal = {Neurocomputing},
 volume = {72},
    pages = {2155-2170},
    year = {2009}

}      I use \cite as well as \citep.

Comment: Try including a citation, as well as some text in the MWE, that way it would be in a more realistic form.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use package apacite. Instead, use

```
\bibliographystyle{model5-names}
\biboptions{authoryear}
```

The model5-names bibliography style is included in the sample manuscript you can download from [www.elsevier.com/latex](http://www.elsevier.com/latex).